# Find number of distinct ways in which balls can be distributed.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, balls-in-bins

> 8 distinct boxes are placed in a line. Each box contains at least 1 and at most 8 red balls. The maximum difference of the number of balls between adjacent boxes is 1. How many distinct cases are there of the number of balls in the boxes?

So I first started with labeling the boxes $a_1$ through $a_8$. Then we write the inequalities pertaining to the differences of the number of balls:
$\lvert a_1 - a_2 \rvert \lt 1$, $\lvert a_2 - a_3 \rvert \lt 1$ and so on. However, this seems like it leads to a lot of messy casework. Is there any way to avoid this and maybe find a cleaner solution?

Comment: I guess you meant $|a_1-a_2| \leq 1$

Answer (score 4):

I don't usually deal with combinatorics, so there has to be more elegant solution, but here is what I got:

We are basically looking for number of sequences $(a_1,\ldots,a_8)$ such that
$$a_i\in\{1,\ldots,8\},\quad i=1,\ldots,8;$$
$$|a_{i+1}-a_{i}|\leq 1,\quad i=1,\ldots,7.$$

We can have $22$ possible different pairs of $(a_4,a_5)$: $8$ pairs of $(i,i)$, $7$ pairs of $(i,i+1)$ and 7 pairs of $(i+1,i)$.
Notice that the number of sequences of length $4$ which lead to $a_4=i$, is the same as number of sequences of length $4$ that lead out of $a_5=i$. It means that if we know these numbers for each $i=1,\ldots,8$, then we can count all sequences by looking at all possible pairs $(a_4,a_5)$. For example, if we denote $l_i, l_j$ as numbers of possible sequences leading to $a_4=i$ and $a_4=j$ respectively, then the number of all sequences with $(a_4,a_5) = (i,j)$ is $l_i\cdot l_j$ (provided that $|i-j|\leq 1$).

We will only look at sequences leading out of $a_5 = 1,2,3,4$, because the numbers that we'll get are the same for $a_5 = 8,7,6,5$ respectively.

Let's start with the easiest case of $a_5=4$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
a_5 & a_6 & a_7 & a_8\\
\hline
 & & &1\\
 & &2&2\\
 &3&3&3\\
4&4&4&4\\
 &5&5&5\\
 & &6&6\\
 & & &7
\end{array}$$

We can see that there are $3^3$ possible sequences that lead out of $a_5=4$, and all of them fit our rules. It means that $l_4 = l_5 = 27$, which is the number of sequences leading out of $a_5=4$ and number of sequences leading out of $a_5=5$. As noted before, this is also the number of sequences leading to $a_4=4$ and the number of sequences leading to $a_5=5$.

Let's look at $a_5=3$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
a_5 & a_6 & a_7 & a_8\\
\hline
 & & &0\\
 & &1&1\\
 &2&2&2\\
3&3&3&3\\
 &4&4&4\\
 & &5&5\\
 & & &6
\end{array}$$

We see that there is one sequence, that doesn't fit our rules: one with $a_8=0$. It means that $l_3 = l_6 = 27-1 = 26$.

Now let's look at $a_5 = 2$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
a_5 & a_6 & a_7 & a_8\\
\hline
 & & &-1\\
 & &0&0\\
 &1&1&1\\
2&2&2&2\\
 &3&3&3\\
 & &4&4\\
 & & &5
\end{array}$$
There is $1$ path that leads to $a_7=0$, and from there we get $3$ possible outcomes for $a_8$. There are also two paths that lead to $a_8=0$ through $a_7=1$. That means that there are $l_2=l_7=27-3-2=22$ sequences that fit our rules.

Let's look at the last case of $a_5 = 1$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
a_5 & a_6 & a_7 & a_8\\
\hline
 & & &-2\\
 & &-1&-1\\
 &0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1\\
 &2&2&2\\
 & &3&3\\
 & & &4
\end{array}$$

There is $1$ path leading up to $a_6=0$, which then produces $3^2$ possible outcomes. There is $1$ path to $a_7=0$ through $a_6=1$, which produces $3$ possible outcomes. Lastly, there are $2$ paths leading up to $a_8=0$, where $a_6\neq 0$ and $a_7\neq 0$. It means that $l_1 = l_8 = 27 -9 - 3-2 = 13$.

We can now calculate numbers of sequences, that lead to each possible pair $(a_4,a_5)$. Let $N_{i,j} = l_i\cdot l_j$ be the number of sequences with $(a_4=i,a_5=j)$. Then:
$$N_{1,1} = N_{8,8} = 13^2\\
N_{2,2} = N_{7,7} = 22^2\\
N_{3,3} = N_{6,6} = 26^2\\
N_{4,4} = N_{5,5} = N_{4,5} = N_{5,4}=27^2\\
N_{1,2} = N_{2,1} = N_{7,8} = N_{8,7}=13\cdot 22\\
N_{2,3} = N_{3,2} = N_{6,7} = N_{7,6}=22\cdot 26\\
N_{3,4} = N_{4,3} = N_{5,6} = N_{6,5}=26\cdot 27\\
$$

Our desired number is
$$\sum_{1\leq i\leq j\leq 8}N_{i,j} = 11814.$$

I would greatly appreciate any comments, because I'm not very familiar with this kind of math-contest problems.

Edit: For anyone still interested, I checked this numerically in python and the result is in fact correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is the number of left-to-right paths in an $8\times8$ grid with appropriate restriction of steps. We count the number of prefix paths that lead to each cell by taking the sum of each cell's predecessors. The total number of paths is the sum of the eighth column.

\begin{array}{r}
1&2&5&13&35&96&267&750\\
1&3&8&22&61&171&483&1372\\
1&3&9&26&75&216&622&1791\\
1&3&9&27&80&235&686&1994\\
1&3&9&27&80&235&686&1994\\
1&3&9&26&75&216&622&1791\\
1&3&8&22&61&171&483&1372\\
1&2&5&13&35&96&267&750\\[2ex]
&\quad\quad&\quad\quad&\quad\quad&\quad\quad&\quad\quad&\quad\quad&11814\end{array}